# Mostrar PDF en Window() WPF C#

Tags: c#, pdf, wpf, .netframework

Tengo un proyecto WPF C# con NET FRAMEWORK 4.8
Estuve buscando alguna solución para incluir un PDF en una Window() de WPF, donde me topé con varios ejemplos/librerias que usaban .NET Core y no me sirvieron, no comprendo mucho, solo necesito que se muestre el PDF dentro del Window().
Este PDF está almacenado localmente en el disco duro.

Si pudieran ayudarme porfavor, conozco basicamente C#.